# NextGen plugin check failing, why?

Tags: jquery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the NextGen plugin check to work. The plugin used to work but now won't load at all. I get this error on the plugin check:

Check theme compatibility
Missing the call to in your theme

I have looked on the net and came up with this thread:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-missing-the-call-to-in-your-theme-after-switching-to-new-theme

And added the:

1. Add `<?php wp_head(); ?>` to your "header.php" right before `</head>`
2. Add `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` to your "footer.php" right before `</body>`

as it stated in the thread. However, the plugin check still gives the error above (and consequently will not work -- it won't work anywhere on the site).

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to try next? The site I am supporting is http://cdnsba.org/ and you can see a big white space on the front left where the slideshow used to work perfectly.

I have a hunch that something is clashing with jQuery since it looks like the "Featured" section on the right doesn't scroll anymore either...

Thanks!

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

The latest release updates the jquery and some plugins had issues with that, you can always upload the older version in the wp-includes directory.

I took a sneak peek in the code and the following snippet should be the culprit.

```
function ngg_ajax_test_head_footer() {

// Build the url to call, NOTE: uses home_url and thus requires WordPress 3.0
$url = add_query_arg( array( 'test-head' => '', 'test-footer' => '' ), home_url() );
// Perform the HTTP GET ignoring SSL errors
$response = wp_remote_get( $url, array( 'sslverify' => false ) );
// Grab the response code and make sure the request was sucessful
$code = (int) wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
if ( $code == 200 ) {
    global $head_footer_errors;
    $head_footer_errors = array();

    // Strip all tabs, line feeds, carriage returns and spaces
    $html = preg_replace( '/[\t\r\n\s]/', '', wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

    // Check to see if we found the existence of wp_head
    if ( ! strstr( $html, '<!--wp_head-->' ) )
        die('Missing the call to <?php wp_head(); ?> in your theme');
    // Check to see if we found the existence of wp_footer
    if ( ! strstr( $html, '<!--wp_footer-->' ) )
        die('Missing the call to <?php wp_footer(); ?> in your theme');
}
die('success');
```

This snippet loads your homepage body and checks if the wp_head and wp_footer are there. As you said you added these so that shouldnt be the problem. What I find strange is that you are missing a part of the die message, the wp_footer or wp_header parts.

As far as i can Tell it looks for < ! - - wp_head - - > (the comment) and not the actual code, the comments dont seem to be shown in your code did you add those?

Comment: I am using the "use google libraries" plugin to use them from Google. I even disabled that plugin and it didn't make any difference...

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell how many jquery scripts are loading and what versions they are?

Comment: I tried "downgrading" jquery but it didn't seem to matter. I wonder if there is something wrong with the edits made to the theme?

Comment: Not sure what call you would be missing, did you try turning on debugging mode in wp-config see if you can get more information from that.

Comment: I got it to finally recognize the wp_head (w3 total cache was wiping out the comment). However, while the plugin validates, it still doesn't work. I have a feeling it is some sort of conflict with the theme jquery or something that is going on.